# Linq-to-Sql NotSupportedException: Can I be sure it will work on a newer server version?

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

I am doing a small reporting project that needs to read a lot of data from an SQL Server 2000 database. I am using Linq-to-SQL; and when I run one of my queries, I get this Exception:

```
NotSupportedException: Cannot translate expression to SQL for this server version
```

This message indicates that my query will work on a newer server version. But can I be sure that it will run on a newer version, and how do I determine which version is needed ?

Perhaps I can upgrade to SQL Server 2008, but it has a cost in both time and money. Therefore, I would like to know whether it would help me in this situation.

Comment: Any chance you could do a test-installation of a SQL Server 2008 eval copy and test your LINQ queries against that, just to see if they do work? That might give you an idea if it's worth upgrading!

Comment: @marc_s, yes that will be my next move.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any version *later* than 2000 should work for you.  This probably has to do with the fact that SQL 2000 does not support VARCHAR(MAX) and VARBINARY(MAX) datatypes, though you never know -- it depends on what exactly you're trying to do, I guess.

The cold hard truth is that SQL 2000 is **9** years old now.  It's time to upgrade.  You're way late to the party.  [SQL 2000 isn't even supported by Microsoft's "mainstream" support structure](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlreleaseservices/archive/2007/07/12/sql-server-support-lifetimes-customer-actions.aspx).  The new technologies have to assume some reasonable window of product stack underneath them, and for Linq to SQL, it pretty much starts with SQL 2005.

Comment: Yes, SQL Server 2000 is old, and I hate being forced to keep supporting it. But we have legacy systems that cannot be upgraded due to (and I quote the DBA) "legacy reasons". :-(

Comment: Then stop trying to do new things with the old, "legacy" systems.